# Mail merge, one email per person, multiple values

Tags: excel, mailmerge

I have an Excel file with the following column headings: First Name, Last Name, Email Address, File Name, File Path. Each person has multiple rows that identify different files names and file paths. I need to use this file with mail marge and send one email to each recipient with locations of their multiple files in a bullet point format.

I appreciate any help on this.

I've tried the following rule to no avail:

- ```
  { IF { MERGEFIELD "Email Address" } = "«Email Address»" "{ MERGEFIELD "File Path" \* MERGEFORMAT }" "" }
  ```

What I'd like to have is one email to Jim Alexander and one to Sasah Bobbijon similar to the following:

---

Dear Jim,

Please refer to the following list and clean up the files:

- ```
  iewi.pst
  ```
- ```
  s98wekfds.pst
  ```

---

Sample Excel sheet:

```
First Name  Last Name   Email Address       File Name   File Path
Jim     Alexander   jim.alexander@email.com iewi.pst    C:\temp\ereer
Jim     Alexander   jim.alexander@email.com s98wekfds.pst   C:\temp\psdsd
Jim     Alexander   jim.alexander@email.com poles.pst   C:\temp\23kddfd
Jim     Alexander   jim.alexander@email.com folksreit.pst   C:\temp\ldsfff
```

Comment: See: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/38721-microsoft-word-catalogue-directory-mailmerge-tutorial.html, especially the part about using DATABASE fields in the mailmerge.

Answer (score 0):

Came to a realization that mail merge rules cannot handle this situation so I came up with a workaround:

- Filter the main sheet by users
- Copy each user dataset to a separate sheet
- Concatenate rows that needs to be on one record into one cell
- Remove additional rows belonging to same user (by this point, all the data for one user is contained in one row)
- Run through mail merge as usual